# ArcGIS: Locate features along routes, line vs polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, line, route

I want to use Locate Features along Routes to locate the polylines below:

[image]

The routed feature is in red and I want to locate the green lines. I have buffered these but found it only locates the item when the buffer intersects the route. Would running this just on the liner items with a locate radius of ~9m still have the effect I'm after? I have >500 features I want to locate and I am asking because I need to be very accurate and do not trust manual validation alone to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function ([Locate Features Along Routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000037000000)) should locate any lines within the search radius without any need for buffering. Be aware that the function will give you results against both branches for the part north of the intersection, as both "legs" will be within the radius.

The result will be a table with the from-to measures from your routes per object in your input per route within the search radius.

Comment: Thank you, as the precaution I had unique line ID in both original file and output and deleted those which did not match.